# Compilation failed: remote: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error When pushing to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I am trying to push an RoR web app to Heroku, but I am getting the following build error:

```
remote:        Compilation failed:
remote:        ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../stylesheets/application' in '/tmp/build_7e435f25/app/javascript/packs'
remote:            at /tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:925:10
remote:            at /tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22
remote:            at /tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21
remote:            at /tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22
remote:            at /tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2830:7
remote:            at /tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:6877:13
remote:            at /tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25
remote:            at /tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:213:14
remote:            at /tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
remote:            at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
remote:            at /tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7
remote:            at /tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
remote:            at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
remote:            at /tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
remote:            at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
remote:            at /tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43
remote:            at /tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
remote:            at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
remote:            at /tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/RootPlugin.js:37:38
remote:            at _next42 (eval at create (/tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:8:1)
remote:            at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:31:1)
remote:            at /tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
remote:            at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
remote:            at /tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43
remote:            at /tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
remote:            at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
remote:            at /tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
remote:            at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
remote:            at /tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DirectoryExistsPlugin.js:27:15
remote:            at /tmp/build_7e435f25/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:85:15
remote:        resolve '../stylesheets/application' in '/tmp/build_7e435f25/app/javascript/packs'
remote:          using description file: /tmp/build_7e435f25/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/packs)
remote:            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:            using description file: /tmp/build_7e435f25/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/stylesheets/application)
remote:              no extension
remote:                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                /tmp/build_7e435f25/app/javascript/stylesheets/application doesn't exist
remote:              .mjs
remote:                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                /tmp/build_7e435f25/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.mjs doesn't exist
remote:              .js
remote:                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                /tmp/build_7e435f25/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.js doesn't exist
remote:              .sass
remote:                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                /tmp/build_7e435f25/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.sass doesn't exist
remote:              .scss
remote:                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                /tmp/build_7e435f25/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss doesn't exist
remote:              .css
remote:                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                /tmp/build_7e435f25/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.css doesn't exist
remote:              .module.sass
remote:                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                /tmp/build_7e435f25/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.module.sass doesn't exist
remote:              .module.scss
remote:                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                /tmp/build_7e435f25/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.module.scss doesn't exist
remote:              .module.css
remote:                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                /tmp/build_7e435f25/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.module.css doesn't exist
remote:              .png
remote:                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                /tmp/build_7e435f25/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.png doesn't exist
remote:              .svg
remote:                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                /tmp/build_7e435f25/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.svg doesn't exist
remote:              .gif
remote:                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                /tmp/build_7e435f25/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.gif doesn't exist
remote:              .jpeg
remote:                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                /tmp/build_7e435f25/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.jpeg doesn't exist
remote:              .jpg
remote:                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                /tmp/build_7e435f25/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.jpg doesn't exist
remote:              as directory
remote:                /tmp/build_7e435f25/app/javascript/stylesheets/application doesn't exist
remote:        
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 6cb1ee551129b46d6adf70c5e8e9788d0c8605f5
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 6cb1ee551129b46d6adf70c5e8e9788d0c8605f5
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to bee-arquitetura.
remote:
```

I have tried looking at the bootstrap Sass documentation [Bootstrap Sass Webpack doc][1]

I originally had a Sass error which I was able to work through but I am not able to figure out what might be causing this error.

Comment: You will have to provide more details about the files that are being compiled (modules used in your Javascript) but this looks like its an error connected to naming of files and modules check your imports of js files for case sensitivity and file names and locations. File extensions also do play a part. Maybe a file you are requiring is in a format, that your webpack config does not expect?

Answer (score 1):

try to edit 'application.js' in the path 'app/javascript/packs/application.js' to:

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"

Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()

import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap'
require("stylesheets/application.scss")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to rename you "application" file (path: app/assets/stylesheets) and add an extension like ".css"

actual name: "application"

modified name: "application.css"

(path: app/assets/stylesheets)

[image: rename your application file]